# Magento: Prioritize Module Loading

Tags: magento, module

There is an existing third-party module that overrides existing Mage functionalities. Let's call it "Foo". Obviously, it resides in the local folder in order to override Core functionalities. As I started working on the project, I had yet to create another module to override few features of the Foo module. Let's call it "Bar". Both are successfully loaded (backend says it is loaded). The problem is that Foo module still takes precedence over Bar and Bar modules don't seem to work. I have two questions regarding this:

1. Am I right to speculate that Magento prioritize modules not only by 
   Core, Enterprise, local model but also in reverse alphabetical
   order, that is, even if both modules are in local folder, Foo
   superceeds Bar?
2. If this is true, how can I make Bar have precedence over Foo module?

Thanks and hoping somebody could shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have 2 modules, My_Foo and My_Bar, and you want the Foo to be loaded before Bar.
To do it, in your Bar module xml file (Under /app/etc/modules/My_Bar.xml), just add:

```
<depends>
<My_Foo/>
</depends>
```

Now the My_Foo module is loaded before the My_Bar

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. Module Foo gets prioritize which, I assume, is the reason why Bar seems to be ignored. I want duplicate methods of Bar to be given priority in case of ambiguity with Foo.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm remembering this correctly (Ben, if I am wrong, just smack me) but you should be able to control this in your module.xml file (Foo_Bar.xml under /app/etc/modules).

Just drop in

```
<depends>
    <Foo_Bar>
</depends>
```

...right after the  node. The value should be the in the standard "Namespace_Modulename" format.

Comment: Thanks, psphan. Would you be so kind to elaborate on this one a bit more?